# Tables with 1-1 relation (information & statistic)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with tables for videos/users/messages.

The video table contains the video information

- id
- title
- description
- owner
- ...

A bunch of statistic (that are updated live)

- views
- positive votes
- negative votes
- ...

And also a bunch of calculated values (that are updated once a day or week)

- calculated_votes
- is_popular
- reputation
- ...

I'm ending up with pretty huge tables. Would it make sence to split it up? (table: videos, videos_statistic)
Which would end up being a 1-1 relation.

I've never been a fan of 1-1 relation, are there any "rules" that say when it's ok to have this type of relation?

Comment: What do you mean by pretty huge tables? If you mean in terms of number of columns this shouldn't be a limitation, if you need 100 columns then you need 100 coumns. If you mean in terms of memory then you will end up using more memory with multiple tables. I don't see any reason that one large table indexed properly would be worse than multiple tables. And multiple tables introduces further maintenance problems. Are you actually having any performance problems?

Comment: For this kind of use (some columns mostly stable, some being updated very often and some rarely) I'd choose splitting the table into 3.

Comment: It also depends on how your stats are used. You may want to move your stats completely to an OLAP environment.

Comment: @GarethD I wasn't clear but I was curious about both. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would keep the stats in a seperate table (1 to many date based, so not 1 to 1)

So the stats table can have columns

- VideoID
- StatDate
- Views
- PositiveVotes
- Etc.

This will allow you to keep a history of the values, which can be used in reporting later, showing averages, trends etc.

Comment: I haven't tought of history, great point. This will help me clear things up.

Comment: Also remember to store a calculated/modified date, as this might come in handy later if values were to be updated, and you need check if you need to recalculate.

Answer (score 1):

I would also keep stats in separate table for two reason(even if its 1-1) :

1:updating a slim table will be easier from resource perspective compared to wider table.
2:Retrieval will also be faster based on kind of reports built.if the data is used for BI Reports.

Considering the attributes mentioned in your question:

id
title
description
owner

These attributes change very rarely once in the system. Where as Statistiques tables gets updated regularly. So as Astander mentioned if you want to maintain statistics at a different grain at date level aswell then non changing attributes need not be stored again again for each day.

Hope this helps.